# Prove that : $(a-b)(a-c)(a-d)(b-c)(b-d)(c-d)$ divisible by $12$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that : $(a-b)(a-c)(a-d)(b-c)(b-d)(c-d)$ divisible by $12$, with $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}$ *every* element is divisible by $12$. Didn't you mean
$a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z}$ sory all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As drhab pointed out, $a,b,c,d$ must be integers.

Since each of $a,b,c,d$ is either even or odd, there are at least two pairs which have the same parity. Hence, the given value is a multiple of $4$.

Since each of $a,b,c,d$ is either $0,1$, or $2$ in mod $3$, there is at least one pair which is congruent in mod $3$. Hence, the given value is a multiple of $3$.