# Solving a divisibility problem using group theory

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, alternative-proof

Inspired by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632699/prove-that-a-ba-ca-db-cb-dc-d-divisible-by-12) I decided to show this:

> Let $P_n=\displaystyle\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n} \big(x_i-x_j\big)$ where $x_1\,\dots\, x_n$ are arbitrary integers. Prove $n!\,\big|\, 2P_n$.

I am wondering whether this can be done using a slick, group theoretic argument.

**Ideas:**

If $X$ is the set of polynomials in $n$ variables, we can consider $S_n$ acting on $X$ likewise:

$$\pi \Big( p(x_1,\,\dots,\,x_n)\Big)=p\Big(x_{\pi (1)},\,\dots,\,x_{\pi (n)}\Big)$$

Then $\text{stab} \big(P_n\big)=A_n$ so $n!$ divides $2\big|\,\text{stab} \big(P_n\big)\big|$. I'd like to think this can be used to derive the result, but I may be wrong. If not on the other hand, a hint would be great.

Comment: it may become true if you change $n!$ into $(n-1)!$. YOu can also easily prove it using induction + pigeonhole principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not seem to be true in general. Look at $\{5,4,3,2,1\}$ Then
$$P_n = (5-4)(5-3)(5-2)(5-1)(4-3)...(3-1)(2-1)=4!3!2!1!$$
In this case $2P_n$ is not divisible by $5!$, as $2P_n$ is not divisible by $5$.

A similar case can happen whenever $n$ is prime.

Comment: Oops, I should have checked before embarking on a proof.