# For $a,b,c,d\in \Bbb N$ prove that $(a-b)(c-a)(d-a)(c-b)(d-b)(d-c)$ is divisible by $12$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

> Given that $a,b,c,d\in \Bbb N$ and pairwise distinct, prove that the number
>   $$(a-b)(c-a)(d-a)(c-b)(d-b)(d-c)\tag{1}$$
>   is divisible by $12$.
>
> Source: IME 1999/2000 entrance exam

**My attempt:**
Suppose WLG that $a<b<c<d$, and $p,q,r$ are defined as
$$p=|a-b|,q=|c-b|,t=|d-c|.$$ 
Therefore the original problem is equivalent (as signs are not relevant here), to finding that
$$P=p q r(p+q)(q+t)(p+q+t)\tag{2}$$
is divisible by 12, with $p,q,t\in \Bbb N$ and $p,q,t\ge 1$.

The problem is now showing that $P$ is divisible by 4 and by 3. To do that let us consider the possibilities for the parity (E=even, O=odd) for the numbers $p,q,t$ and see what happens to the parity of the other terms of the product $P$:
$$
\begin{array}{ l| c | c | c| c| c|c }
    case&p&q&t&(p+q)&(q+t)&(p+q+t)\\
  \hline 
       1&E&E&E&  E&    E&     E \\
       2&E&E&O&  E&    O&     O \\
       3&E&O&E&  O&    O&     O \\
       4&O&E&E&  O&    E&     O \\
       5&O&O&O&  E&    E&     O \\
       6&E&O&O&  O&    E&     E\\
       7&O&E&O&  O&    O&     E\\
       8&O&O&E&  E&    O&     E\\
  \hline  
\end{array}
$$
In all 8 cases, there are at least 2 even terms and, as each even term can be represented by $2k_i$, we will have $4k_i k_j$ as a factor in $P$ and therefore $P$ is divisible by 4.

**Question**: how can I show that $P$ is divisible by 3? It appears true but I'm not finding a simple formal argument to show that. There is another similar SE math question in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632699/prove-that-a-ba-ca-db-cb-dc-d-divisible-by-12) , but the argument in the answer is not sufficient clear for me.  I'm looking for an argument that is appealing for a 7th grader concerning the divisibility by 3, if that is possible.

Previous answer used, for instance, the notation "congruent in mod 3" that is not something appealing for a 7th grader. I'm looking for a simpler argument using terminology appealing for this level.

**Postscript**:

Given the helpful comment from Ronald below, I will try a complete explanation for the "divisibility by 3 part":

Now considering the same notation using $p,q,t$, it must be the case that for some $k_1,k_2,k_3\in \Bbb N$ it holds that
$$p=3 k_1+r_1, q=3 k_2+r_2, t=3 k_3+r_3$$
in which $r_1,r_2,r_3$ are the rests from the division of $p,q,t$ by 3. Therefore 
$r_1,r_2,r_3\in\{0,1,2\}$, in which $r_i=0$ denotes a case in which the number is divisible by 3. Let us now examine the possibilities for $r_i$ in $p,q,t$.

First, for at least one $r_i=0$, we are done because we have a factor in (2) divisible by 3. Now for the other possibilities. The table shows the rest for the division by 3 of the terms:
$$
\begin{array}{ l| c | c | c| c| c|c }
    case&p&q&t&(p+q)&(q+t)&(p+q+t)\\
  \hline 
       1&1&1&1&  2&    2&     0 \\
       2&1&1&2&  2&    3&     1 \\
       3&1&2&1&  0&    0&     1 \\
       4&2&1&1&  0&    2&     1 \\
       5&2&2&1&  1&    3&     2 \\
       6&2&1&2&  0&    0&     2 \\
       7&1&2&2&  0&    1&     2 \\
       8&2&2&2&  1&    1&     0 \\
  \hline  
\end{array}
$$
The rest for each of the terms $(p+q),(q+t),(p+q+t)$ can be found by adding the rests from the terms in each sum, and if this value is greater than 2, dividing this value again by 3, to find the rest. For example, in the first row, the rest for $(p+q+t)$ would be $(1+1+1)=3$, with rest 0 from the division by 3.

Therefore, as each line in this last table has at least one term with rest 0 with respect to the division by 3, we have proved that $P$ is divisible by 3.

As Ronald suggested in the comments, this can be seen more easily with the original problem defined in terms of $a,b,c,d$. Because the rest of the division by 3 can be only 0,1,2, it must be the case that at least 2 of these numbers have the same rest with respect to 3, and if two numbers have the same rest with respect to $n$, their difference will have rest zero or will be divided by that number, as
$(k_1n+r)-(k_2n+r)=(k_1-k_2)n$ 
the rest with respect to $n$ is zero. Therefore in (1) we must have a term divisible by 3.

It is helpful to note, concerning math terminology that if two numbers have the same rest with respect to a number $n$, we can call these two numbers "congruent mod n". Therefore 0,3 and 6 are congruent mod 3 because all have rest 0 with respect with the division by 3. 1 and 4 are congruent mod 3 because 1 and 4 have rest 1 with respect to the division by 3.

Comment: That is mentioned in the question, see why it was asked.

Comment: After dividing a number by 3 you'll have a remainder of 0, 1 or 2. Since you have 4 numbers ($a, b, c, d$), at least two of them have the same remainder after dividing by 3. WLG say that are $a$ and $b$. Then $a - b$ will have a remainder of zero after dividing by 3, in other words, $a - b$ is a multiple of 3.

Comment: Why is "congruent modulo $3$" not appealing to a 7th grader? It's on the same level as "odd/even" for me. If the problem is terminology, then it's just a matter of putting it in simpler term, as done by Ronald in the comment above mine.

Comment: This terminology "congruent modulo 3" is not in the 7th grader level (or below) books that I know, odd/even, yes, divisibility rules, yes. And thanks a lot for @Ronald for explaining in a way that is understandable without the use of more advanced terminology.

Comment: Just correct the table to include missing cases.

Comment: The question is not a dupe of the linked questions since it is constrained by proofs accessible at 7th grade level. So I have reopened it.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a proof accessible at $7$th grade level. Note that the product contains *all* possible differences of $a,b,c,d$ so to prove it is divisible by $3$ it suffices to prove that one such difference is divisible by $3$. We use a *pigeonhole argument*: we have $4$ integers $\,a,b,c,d\,$ but only $3$ possible remainders $\,0,1,2\,$ for division by $3$, therefore two integers have the same remainder $\color{#c00}r,\,$ hence their difference $\,3q\!+\!\color{#c00}r  - (3q'\!+\!\color{#c00}r) = 3(q\!-\!q')$ is divisible by $3,\,$  therefore the product $n$ has a factor of $3$.

Similarly two of them $\,x,y\,$ leave the same remainder $r$ after division by $2$ so $x-y$ is divisible by $2$. If there is another $\,z\,$ with remainder $r$ then also $y-z$ is divisible by $2;$ else the other two numbers have remainder $\neq r$ so they have equal remainders (since there are only $2$ possible remainders $0,1$), so their difference is divisible by $2$. Hence the product $n$ has *two* factors of $2,\,$ so it is divisible by $4$.

Finally $\ \color{#c00}3,\color{#0a0}4\mid n\,\Rightarrow\,12\mid n,\ $ by $\  n = \underbrace{4(n)}_{\Large 4(\color{#c00}3j)}\! -\! \underbrace{3(n)}_{\Large 3(\color{#0a0}4k)} = 12(j\!-\!k)$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure, however, whether the notation $3,4 |n$, understood as $3$ and $4$ divide $n$, is usual at the 7th grade.

Comment: @bluemaster Yes, of course you should use whatever notation is appropriate. The point of the answer is to explain to *you* how to present such an argument.